# Why Sourcetree does not support the use of '/' in Git-flow branch names?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

When I try to create a new feature I press **Git-flow -> Start New Feature** and if I chose a branch name like this: *model/user* in the end the complete branch name should be ***feature***/model/user but instead I get an error:

```
The name is invalid. Ref names must follow git ref-format rules: 
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html
Additionally Sourcetree does not support the use of '/' in Git-flow branch names
Completed with errors, see above.
```

- SourceTree version: **3.1.3**
- Git-flow version: **1.11.0 (AVH Edition)**

Before this update branch names could contain '/' and were displayed as an arborescent structure.

If I use [git flow commands](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac) it works and new branch appears in SourceTree.

Is this a bug or it's a normal behaviour?

Comment: Which version of Git flow are you using? The version can be retrieved using the `git flow version` command.

Comment: I updated my question with git flow version, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding the version, Robert. I believe, updating to the latest Git flow version should solve your problem. I had similar issues when using an older version recently - updating Git flow made the problem disappear.

Comment: I am not sure if I am answering for the same root cause but I had this exact error and it turned out, I wasn't supposed to be typing `/feature` in my branch name (at all). Also turned out that [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Re-Is-GitFlow-integration-broken-for-SourceTree-3-1-2/qaq-p/1155086/comment-id/30660#M30660) was the solution.

Comment: @petrosmm I was not typing "/feature" in my branch name. Sourcetree was supposed to autocomplete this keyword before my branch name. For example I used "model/user" as branch name and after autocomplete, the name should be: "feature/model/user"

Comment: @Robert I am assuming sourcetree did not add '/feature/ infront of the name correct?

Comment: @petrosmm You have to add git flow to your project if you want Sourcetree to autocomplete with keywords on branch names.

Comment: Yes Robert, I am aware, this is what I was seeing when I did that. [img](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/63415i105A91D213C4DBA3/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, updating to the latest Git flow version should solve your problem. I had similar issues when using an older version recently - updating Git flow made the problem disappear.

Comment: How can I update git flow? All searching leads to the functionality of "updating".

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-git-flow-config) please. Here you will find command: `git flow config set`. Also `git flow help` might help.

Comment: seriously, how do you update git flow?  the fact that it works fine in git-flow from the command, and that the error is specific to Sourcetree, seems to suggest that it's not a git-flow problem.  also @Robert's link is just for updating _a setting_, not git-flow itself.

Comment: @drzaus I think it has to be a compatibility between SourceTree version and git-flow version. From what I remember, at that time I didn't have the latest version of git-flow. I don't remember how I updated it, maybe remove it and install it again will help.